# Last Event Triggered by Plugin

Tags: plugin, jevents

I need to know which event is most probably the last one triggered in normal application flow.

The Event should be triggered after all default controller actions have been run, the template is rendered and possibly already delivered and the next step in the application would be its own shutdown.

I found the events:

- onAfterRoute
- onAfterDispatch

But is there another one, called later?

Thanks in Ahead!

**EDIT**

During development I switched on the debug mode of Joomla! and on the Screenshoot below the answer to my question appeared even coloured…

[image]

Comment: Good question. It would be nice if they has specified somewhere on the plugin event docs which order they get triggered in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found them to fire in this order. Nothing in the docs to my knowledge, but just tested to confirm:

1. onAfterInitialise()
2. onAfterRoute()
3. onAfterDispatch()
4. onBeforeRender()
5. onBeforeCompileHead()
6. onAfterRender()

Comment: +1, just out of curiosity, how did you test them?

Comment: In each of the events of the plugin I put `echo '<pre>'.__METHOD__.'</pre>'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer helped me a lot! Have a look at my edit, I found that on the way…